# Texture mapping with multiple UV maps

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

So, as a newbie relatively new to blender, I started doing some texture mapping (blender internal Render). I created a texture for the main object and a couple of transparent decals to decorate it. (basic effects made in GIMP). Simple stuff, just to know how it works.

After unwrapping, having 2 UV maps made, creating both new material and textures, enabling UV mapping coordination I always end up with:
 - all - 1 faces of the cube being covered nicely in the main texture
 - 1 face covered in blank material with a decal in the middle of it
 - the whole thing partly coated by a huge "stain" of a decal

So, the problem is that I can't layer textures correctly. Is there a way to have one texture covering everything and more transparent ones on top of it?
I am working on a bigger project right now and having this ability would be useful

Answer (score 11):

1. First unwrap the cube (I used *Follow Active Quads*).
2. Add the default Color grid image texture as the image.
3. Add a new UV map (I called it *decal*). In order to do that open Properties Editor > Data tab > *UV maps* rollout and press "+" button. Select the face you want the decal on and press <kbd>U</kbd> >*Unwrap*.
4. Add another image texture in the second texture slot, set the UV map to *decal* and the set the *Extension* to *Clip*.

[image: texture settings]
Both image textures are on the same material. The material is not specific to any face, it is on the entire model. The UV maps control where the textures go.

Here is the result, default Color grid as the texture and the blender logo as the decal.
[image: end result]

Comment: Hi, I have a quick question, whats the limit on how many UV Maps you can have on one object?