# How to unwrap two image textures onto one object without deforming the UV mapping of either texture

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, objects, uv-image-editor

I've been having trouble with an effect I'm trying to achieve.
Right now I'm using a 2D texture for black and white tiles that has normals applied in the influence tab. 
[image]

Since I also need a dirty map that I don't want invovled with the normals of the tile texture, I added another texture tab in the material. However, as it stands right now, with the UV texture, the result is not quite right for me.
[image]

Therefore, I tried to scale down the UVs I selected, but when I do, the tiles become bigger. It must be because the UVs for both images are connected, where I cannot change the UV position and size for one image without doing the same for the other.
[image]
[image]

Is there a way for me to change the UV size for one projected image without effecting the UVs for a different image within the same material on the same object?

Maybe I could make a transparent layer above the floor and create an image of the dirty map on top instead, but I want to know if this is possible first...
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use Scale sliders in the texture settings > Mapping rollout (assuming you use Blender Internal, if Cycles use Mapping node). Then the texture will be scaled with its options, not with UV map. Or create another UV map and use it exclusively for dirt material. Afaik no way to scale one UV map used in 2 textures independently.

Comment: Thanks, I looked it up and figured it out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please don't mark the question as solved in the title. Instead write an answer to your own question. Otherwise in the system the question remains unanswered. Please add a detailed answer that might help others.

Comment: Is it okay if I link to the page that solved it? If so, then here's the link to the answer page if anyone needs to know: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18346/texture-mapping-with-multiple-uv-maps

Comment: It is, and thank you, I didn't have enough time to answer my question before I went to work.