# Texture on a flat plane without duplication

Tags: rendering, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I want to add a texture on a flat plane without the texture repeating again and again on the same plane. I have confirmed that the type of texture is "image or movie." I have already selected and loaded the image. I want to use the internal rendering engine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In image mapping try to set extension to **Clip**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cycles option to turn off texture tiling?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1258/cycles-option-to-turn-off-texture-tiling)

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18346/texture-mapping-with-multiple-uv-maps

Answer (score 2):

There is an internal add-on called "Add Images As Planes" This will allow you to import images as a plane with the proper scaling for X and Y. I find it very helpful.