# Node setup for a decal in blender 2.8

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, texture-coordinates

How can I add a second material as a decal?

I am needing to export to collada with 2 materials.  The first material is a base texture build up with the principle shader. The second texture is a decal. I need the decal to be in the 2nd material as when I export it into scenekit. I would like to swap-out material 2 with anybitmap the user chooses in the app. But I will me ensuring that user material is always at the correct UVmap.

So I have created two UVmap as per this answer.

[Texture mapping with multiple UV maps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18346/texture-mapping-with-multiple-uv-maps)

in blender 2.8 the only texture properties I am seeing is a brush. So I've made the decal a brush but I'm not able to apply it.

[image]

As you see in the image above, there are two canvas pictures. The one in the back has the "painting" material applied before creating a 2nd UVmap.
The canvase in the front has it applied but there isn't a decal.

I have seen the cycles/node editor where you use a 2nd texture and mix the color and alpha fracture into the base texture, resulting in a decal.
[mixing textures, same material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15207/setup-a-decal-material-in-cycles)
But that is all in the same material. I need 2 separate materials.

I've created 2 shaders, each shader is using the appropriate UVmap.

[image: painting shader]
[image: base shader]
[blendfile](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51682)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46447/1853)

Comment: @cegaton Are you saying that can be applied to two materials? That's answer was showing the color mixers which I mentioned in my question I was aware of.

Comment: You can use the image to mix different shaders, as explained in the link.

Comment: I've managed to get a variation working after I changed my first shader to a group and added it to my second shader and done the mix in there. I am figuring out exporting before I'm totally sure if it worked as I had hope.