# How to add an additional texture map to places where resolution really matters

Tags: texturing

[image]

I have a human model whose texture map stored on a single `jpeg`. However, because there is alot of topology in the model, the *pixels per inch* of the model become quite low.

In specific, I am noticing this low PPI in places such as the eye brows.

How can I place an additional texture map over the eye brows to give myself plenty of resolution to draw realistic eyebrows in?

Comment: This question is potentially similar to: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18346/texture-mapping-with-multiple-uv-maps

Comment: ^ This is essentially what UDIMs are. In game dev, they usually just call them second or third UV maps, and they tend to be conceptualized as "on top" of one another, where as in VFX where the artist has essentially unlimited texture res to work with they will conceptualize the UDIM as one big texture made of smaller textures like [this](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/5/5/3/5533fb55df479bbc65773ccfe82b5f7296c01cbc.jpeg). All the same thing, at the end of the day.

Comment: can you use a second Image Texture? In that case just create a second UV map that you'll use to put this more detailed painting

Comment: You can scale that part of the UVMap independently of the others, or you can add an other material slot to that area and scale up its uv to fit the screen. In the second case you don't have to create a new UVMap, it doesn't count if it overlapping with other UV islands which belongs to other material.

Comment: @Jakemoyo UDIM's seem to be the most compelling solution for what I want to achieve. Can you add that as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [UDIMs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/modeling/meshes/editing/uv/workflows/udims.html) are what you are looking for.